# Smartedit - Switch between Shop-Users

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, smartedit

We have a website which is only accessible if your are logged in.
Additionally we have components (etc.) which have logic based on the roles of the logged-in user.

Currently, in SmartEdit, one must first log in on the LoginPage with a shop user before being able to perform actions without encountering missing components.

If I want to test the view with another ShopUser it gets really painful.

Is there any solution to that problem? Like a Dropdown where you can register some dummy users so you can switch in a easy way? Without log in with credentials.

Thanks a lot

googled but found nothing. Maybe we implemented something wrong?

We are on SAP Commerce 2211.16